# Vagrant Machines - Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:3001

Tags: vagrant

I am currently setting up a development environment whereby there are two vagrant machines. The first hosts a website etc while the second hosts an API which the website calls. Currently my vagrantfiles are as follows:

API

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3001, host: 3001
end
```

Website

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000
end
```

When i attempt to load the site which makes a call to the API I get:

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:3001 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 3001)):
```

I understand there are multi-machine approaches but as I already have an seperate environment set up for each project I was wondering if there is any way for me to allow the connection between the two. I have looked into changing the hosts file on the vagrant machine hosting the site but not sure what I should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put both VMs into the same private network and `Website` VM will be able to reach `API` VM via it:

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "<ip_address>"
```

For example, for your case:

**API VM:**

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3001, host: 3001
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.200.3"
end
```

**Website VM:**

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.200.2"
end
```

Now, `Website` VM can reach `API` VM on `192.168.200.3:3001`. And of course you can reach `Website` VM on `127.0.0.1:3000` and `API` VM on `127.0.0.1:3001` from your host machine.